# Creating Virtual Box desktop with Linux on my mac

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive, python, virtualization, vdi

I am a novice Python programmer and I am having trouble creating a Virtual Box, hopefully this is an easy fix!

So, I've been using a virtual machine for my computational physics class, but it is connected to my physics department, so I can't use it for my research, I want to create my own. I have a Mac and would like to build a Ubuntu Linux based virtual machine, but am having trouble.

So I start in the Virtual box Manager and click "New", create a machine type Linux version Ubuntu, keep the default memory size, choose to create a virtual hard disk now (VDI), keep it dynamically allocated, and create the New Virtual Hard Disk on my Desktop. I then try to open it up but then it asks me to "select a virtual optical disk file or physical optical drive containing a disk to start your new virtual machine from" but there is none to select from and it does not work without one.

Can someone see what my problem is? Is there a way I can get this virtual optical disk file? Is there something I can download for free online? I'm sure it's something easy. Thanks if you can give me any advice!

Comment: In your case it is asking you to point to your Ubuntu iso which hopefully you have downloaded somewhere...

Comment: [how to install a iso file on Virtualbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rag4LDoBUC0) ~1:50  If you need a write up still let me know,

Comment: I have not, is that downloading Ubuntu desktop? I tried to download that and it said that there was "no mountable file systems". Do I need a flash drive to mount this on? How to I get an Ubuntu iso? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah! Never mind, that video helped. I got it working! Thank you! This is so exciting.

Comment: It would be nice if you could write an answer to your own question explaining how you managed it, for future use to other folks ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is asking where your Ubuntu ISO is. If you have not downloaded it:

32-bit Ubuntu 16.04: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso

64-bit Ubuntu 16.04: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Then select the file. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a novice it might be the most efficient to just download a preconfigured VB-Image. In any case, it is a definite time-saver.

Check http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/

p.s. Don't forget to install virtualbox extension pack on the host and guest-additions inside of the guest.